# Can’t check db data in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, amazon-rds

I was using the rds connection from the express (type orm + postgresql) server, but I moved to the nestjs (typeorm + postgresql) server.

If you put db data, the existing express server is added well, and you can check it in dbeaver.

However, in the new nestjs server, if you check the log, there is no existing data, but you have all the added information, and you cannot check it in dbeaver.

Comment: If it';s there in dbeaver, but not in the node application, check that 1) dbeaver is not holding onto a non-committed transaction and 2) that the node application is connected to the same database

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you switched to the NestJS server with Type **ORM**, the existing data in your PostgreSQL database is not visible in logs or in tools like DBeaver. However, when you used the Express server with TypeORM, the existing data was accessible and visible.

This problem may be brought on by one of the following:

Data set association arrangement: Twofold really looks at the data set association design in your **NestJS server**. Check the TypeORM configuration file or environment variables to ensure that the connection details, such as host, port, username, password, and database name, are set appropriately. The server may connect to a different or empty database if the connection settings are not correctly configured.

Differing schemas in databases: Check to see if the database schema used by the Express server and the NestJS server is the same. A logical container for database objects like tables, views, and functions is referred to as a schema. You may not be able to see the existing data if the NestJS server uses a different schema than the Express server. Check to see that the schema is set up on both servers.

Synchronization and migrations: Type **ORM** manages over time changes to the database schema through migrations. Verify that the NestJS server correctly executed the Express server's migrations. The data would not be visible if they were added through migrations in the Express server but not applied in the NestJS server. Consider using the synchronize option with caution to automatically synchronize the schema between the server and the database, or make sure that all necessary migrations are carried out.

Defined entities: Guarantee that the element definitions in the NestJS waiter precisely mirror the construction of the current tables. Verify that the entity names, column names, and relationships are correct. The server may be unable to correctly retrieve the existing data if the entity definitions are incorrect or out of sync with the actual table structure.

**If you look into these possible causes, you should be able to figure out what's causing the problem and fix it.**